# Counting in recursion calls

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I need to write a method that checks how many possible ways there are to finish a grid (a 2D array).

the movement inside the grid is like this:
start with [0][0] take the number inside there (for instance 14) then go to either
`[array.[0][0]%10][array.[0][0]/10]` or `[array.[0][0]/10][array.[0][0]%10]`

for our example:
`[1][4]` or `[4][1]`

until you get to the end of the array (bottom right corner).

I can get to the end of the array (all possible ways) - my problem is to count how many times I actually finished the array - I can not use a variable outside of the method, and the method has to be recursive.

this is the code :

```
private static int howMany(int[][] array, int y, int x, int count) {
    if(y+(array[y][x]%10) < array.length && x+(array[y][x]/10)< array[y].length && array[y][x]!=0) {
        System.out.println("["+y+"]["+x+"] is: "+array[y][x]);
        howMany(array, y+(array[y][x]%10), x+(array[y][x]/10),count);
    }
    if(y+(array[y][x]/10) < array.length && x+(array[y][x]%10)< array[y].length && array[y][x]!=0) {
         System.out.println("["+y+"]["+x+"] is: "+array[y][x]);
         howMany(array, y+(array[y][x]/10), x+(array[y][x]%10),count);
    }
    if(y==array.length-1 && x==array[y].length-1) count++;
    return count;  
}
```

this is obviously wrong and will return what count was in the first place, I tried many other ways but to no avail...
here's the full class (with an array to test):

[link to full class](http://encodable.com/cgi-bin/filechucker.cgi?action=landing&path=/&file=Grid.java)

edit: a big Thanks to everyone for their help!

Answer (score 1):

The `count` is already returned from each call to `howMany`. I think you just need to save it:

```
count = howMany(array, y + (array[y][x] % 10), x + (array[y][x] / 10), count);
```

Do this inside both `if` blocks. I made this change in your linked code and got the expected result (`3`).

Comment: Thanks, I used this (mainly because it required less changes, hehe )

Answer (score 0):

Return 1 if you've reached the end of the array (bottom right corner) and `1+howMany(array, newY, newX)` otherwise. You don't need to keep the count and pass it every time. The function will work so:
1 + `returned value of 2nd call` =
1 + 1 + `returned value of 3rd call` =
1 + 1 + 1 +  `returned value of 4th call` =... and so on.
Finally as result you'll get number of calls which is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You are already on the right track, since your method signature returns an int. You should define a variable to hold the count, increment it for the primary recursive call, and *add* to it the result of the recursive method itself. Passing the count into the each recursive call is unnecessary and should be removed.